# Powerpoint Stacked Columns next to each other

Tags: powerpoint

for a powerpoint presentation I want to show the components of my total costs.

For this I want one column showing the total and something like a stacked column showing the components. But I want each of the components on its own part of the x-Axis as if they were normal columns in a standard column diagramm. But each column should begin on the y-Axis where the column before it ended.

Is there a way to achieve this in powerpoint?

Thanks in advance
Nova

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried, as well as a possible example of what you are trying to achieve (images preferably)?

Comment: This forum is for programming problems. Please post your question at answers.microsoft.com or SuperUser.